# Downloading of WP8 app succeeded, but installing failed

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

I was installing an app for my WP8 Nokia Lumia 920, an app of 200 mb and while I was doing that, I decided to install another app, also a large one. The second one installed correctly, but the first one did not! And if I check the app store, I can't reinstall and if I check my app list, I'm unable to find it. How can I solve this problem!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you go into the Store, is it still in the Downloads list?

Comment: No, nothing. When I open the app in the store, the only possibility I have left is to share it. The download list is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the games. Open games and you will find it there.

Comment: I'm sorry for this silly question, I thought I'd been looking around everywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exploring your app related activity through the web might be your next best option.

Try these steps:

1. Go to the [Windows Phone site](http://www.windowsphone.com/)
2. On the top right corner, hover over `Explore My Phone` and then click `Sign in`
   [image]
3. Once you've signed in, you will see more options available in the same menu. Click on the `Purchase history` option
   [image]
4. You will see a list of downloaded apps. Re-install the one that didn't install correctly the first time
   [image]
5. If you don't see the app that you want to install in that `Purchase history` list, search for the app on the same [Windows Phone site](http://www.windowsphone.com/). For each app, you will see an option on the left to install or re-install the app
   [image]